# Github Enterprise - Only Push Events Show in the Web UI

Tags: github, github-api, github-enterprise

We're using Github Enterprise 2.7.4 and we've noticed that no webhook events show up in the user interface (/:owner/:repo/settings/hooks) except for **push** events. All other events do not show at all, which makes troubleshooting and testing pretty difficult. This seems like a bug...

Comment: If you indeed have an enterprise license you also have access to the premium support. Have you logged an issue and supplied a support bundle? GitHub Enterprise is a closed product so I'd expect it to be hard for the community to help...

Answer (score 1):

So the webhook should be *sending* not *receiving* events.

Are you sure in your webhook configuration under

```
path/to/your/repo/settings/hooks/YOURHOOKID
```

You don't have

> "Just the push event"

Selected?

If you don't I'd suggest pointing the webhook at a utility like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) where you can inspect the payload being sent from the webhook.

Our webhooks are working fine in 2.7.4.

Comment: I've confirmed the webhooks are firing but they're just not showing up at all in the Github UI. Only push events show in the UI. Is this a feature or a bug? We are using 2.7.4 http://imgur.com/a/cxtqL

Comment: Looking at my config, I can see "X-GitHub-Event: status" hook events (+ a number of others) being fired in the UI, I'd suggest you contact support.